# Why am I getting failed to open connection in Crystal Reports method ExportToDisk?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report that users say is working. This application is new to me and [Crystal Reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) is new to me.  The database was backed up and restored to a new SQL Server instance.  The orphaned users were relinked and the report code (shown below) changed to point to the new server. Now it gets the *failed to connect* error. The report is run from C# code.

Here is the code that calls the report, followed by the values at the point the code threw the exception.

```
private void laborRptByJobBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rptFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rptObj = new LaborRptByJob();
            CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo tliEZIS = new TableLogOnInfo();

            tliEZIS.TableName = rptObj.Database.Tables[0].Name;
            tliEZIS.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseServerName"];
            tliEZIS.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "EZIS";
            tliEZIS.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "EZIS";
            tliEZIS.ConnectionInfo.Password = "EZIS";
            rptObj.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(tliEZIS);
            rptObj.SetParameterValue("JobNumber", division.Text.Trim());
            string testPath = rptFolderDialog.SelectedPath + "\\Job " + division.Text.Trim() + " - Labor Report.pdf";
            rptObj.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, testPath);
            //rptObj.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, rptFolderDialog.SelectedPath + "\\Job#: " + division.Text.Trim() + " - Labor Report.pdf");
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this seemingly interesting error message in the watch list upon exception:

```
'rptObj.Database.Tables[0].Location' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
```

I know that implies the use of single quotes to set a string, but I looked through the code and didn't find a direct setting of the location parameter at all or any single quotes.  Also at the same time I set a watch to location and got this:

```
rptObj.Database.Tables[0].Location "LaborReportView" string
```

Other values are:

```
ServerName = "\\\\appdev02\\mssql2017dev"
DatabaseName = "EZIS"
UserId = "EZIS"
Testpath = "\\\\Mac\\Home\\Desktop\\Job 2849 - Labor Report.pdf"
```

In the watch list there are several rows of invalidcastexceptions, such as one on Location and one on Name.  I have used [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) to verify that the EZIS login to the `\\appdev02\mssql2017dev` EZIS database exists with the same password and has rights to the view.

Comment: What is "EZIS"? Is it related to [the monitoring tool](https://www.ezis.cloud/features)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer with help.  The error message was couldn't connect, so I spent time looking at why that might be.  The real problem was the source of the data was a view and the view was broken.  In the old database the view linked to a separate server using openquery().  In the new server the two databases were on the same server, so the "link" was not available.  A simple change to a fully qualified name made it work.

I should have tried to run the view much earlier in the diagnosis of the problem.

Prime learning (relearning): Never trust an error message to indicate exactly what the problem is.